# JSON Schema - array of different objects

Tags: json, swagger, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

I'd like to know how to specify a JSON schema for an array of different objects.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396251/correct-json-schema-for-an-array-of-items-of-different-type#15673308) gives me half the answer, but fails when I have multiple instances of each type of object.

Here's a sample XML, based on the [example given here](http://the-long-dark-tech-time.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/using-json-schema-with-array-of-mixed.html) but with the "*Product*" object being repeated:-

```
{
  "things": [
    {
      "entityType" : "Product",
      "name" : "Pepsi Cola",
      "brand" : "pepsi"
    },
    {
      "entityType" : "Product",
      "name" : "Coca Cola",
      "brand" : "coke"
    },
    {
      "entityType" : "Brand",
      "name" : "Pepsi Cola"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following schema will validate the above XML only when there is a single instance of each type (i.e. if "*Product*" only appears once).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "https://schemas.example.com/things",
  "title": "Things",
  "description": "Some things",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "things"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "things": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "entityType",
            "name"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "entityType": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "Product"
              ]
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "brand": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "entityType",
            "name"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "entityType": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "Brand"
              ]
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

To add to the entertainment, I can't use keywords like "*AnyOf*", as I'm embedding this schema into a Swagger 2.0 document, and those keywords aren't supported.

Thanks,

J.

Comment: Can the objects have other property names that differ? In your example they all have pretty much the same structure, with just the `brand` property being optional.

Comment: No, they're quite different; only a couple of properties have the same name.

Comment: Hmmmm... why the downvote on the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define array of multiple models in Swagger 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096136/define-array-of-multiple-models-in-swagger-2-0)

Answer (score 2):

Without `anyOf` you're out of luck. The best you can do is use one schema that covers all of the options. It not a great solution, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Oh dear.  I was afraid of that.  Swagger's lack of support for these constructs is fixed in Open API 3.0 ...but we're tied to 2.0.  Thanks for the reply.